# Размещение рисунка из массива в div бок

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Приветствую! Суть работы. Код делает клоны необходимых мне ***Div***'ов. Подписываю их при помощи .html и присваиваю нужные значения из массива. Появилась необходимость размещения рисунка в каждый клон. Все необходимое вроде как сделал, рисунок грузится в блок, но не во все, а лишь в последней. Зависимость нашел от цифры указанной в ***For***. Подскажите что не так делаю. Необходимо, чтоб в каждый див-клон летела своя ***Jpжка***.

В этом виде картинка определяется в последний ***Div***.

```js
var Store = [
  ["Name_2", "N_2"],
  ["Name_3", "N_3"],
  ["Name_4", "N_4"]
];

var Sum = Store.length+1;
var Images = [["1.jpg"],["2.jpg"],["3.jpg"]];
var Cover = Images.length;

$(document).ready(function() {


window.onload = function () {

            var oImage = new Image();

            oImage.onload = function () {

             for (var q=0; q<Cover; q++);
             document.getElementById('Image' + '_' + q).src = oImage.src;
              
            

            };
              
              oImage.src = Images[1]; 

};

  var container = $("#container"),
    containers = Store.slice(0).map(function(el, index) 
    {
              var clone = container.clone(); 
clone.children().html(function(i) {  

$('div.Pr').html("<b>Pr: </b>" + el[0]);
$('div.Dr').html("<b>Dr: </b>" + el[1]);


return i[el];
        }).andSelf() 
        .attr("id", function(i, attr) { 
          return attr + '_' + (index + 1);
        });
      return clone; 
    });
  $(".clone-box").append(containers); 
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.tab {
border: 3px double black; 
    background: #; 
    padding: 4px; }
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Clone.css">

<div id="container" class="tab">

<img id="Image" class="Image" src="" width="30" height="30" align="Right"/>
<div id="Pr" class="Pr"><b>Pr: </b>Name</div>
<div id="Dr" class="Dr"><b>Dr: </b>N</div>

</div>

<div class="clone-box"></div>
```

Comment: +1 за слово "Jpжка". Завис на пару секунд, пытаясь понять, что это такое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох сколько всякого замудренного, как я вижу проблема находится именно тут:

```
for (var q=0; q<Cover; q++);
document.getElementById('Image' + '_' + q).src = oImage.src;
```

а именно в точке с запятой сразу после фора. Получается что цикл обрабатывается впустую, без `document.getElementById('Image' + '_' + q).src = oImage.src;` тем самым после выхода с цикла, `q` будет равна самому максимальному значению, и присвоение линка будет лишь единожды.

Хотел бы еще акцентировать внимание на запись массива:

```
var Images = [["1.jpg"],["2.jpg"],["3.jpg"]];
...
oImage.src = Images[1];
```

В этом случае массивы в массиве, и значение `Images[1]` будет массив, а не строка.

Так же не понятно зачем писать `Store.slice(0).map`, конечно ясно что с помощью `slice` можно создать клон массива, но это же делает и функция `map`.

Comment: Убрав запятую после **for**, цикл прервался вообще, ни одной картинки не выводится. По массиву, так и планировалось, но тут не принципиально собственно, он будет перебираться отправляя имена картинок в соответствующий **ID** Imag'а.

Comment: Да все верно, прошу прощение, не проверил сам цикл на правильность, дело в том что Вы начинаете отсчет от 0, код ищет элемент `Image_0`, а его попросту нету, и выскакивает ошибка, после цикл попросту прекращается, нужно либо же изменить цикл, сместив его на еденицу: `for (var q=1; q<Cover + 1; q++)`, либо же начинать отсчет ID с нуля.

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло начало счета с **1**. Теперь в каждую форму мне приходит значение указанное в **oImage.src = Images[1]**, но оно одинаковое, т.к. указано единственное в **Images[1]**. Чтобы в каждую форму шло оригинальные значения каждого элемента массива, необходимо сделать его переборку в этой части **oImage.src = Images[1];**, где image[будет например i]?

Comment: Да, все верно, можно написать что то на подобие:
 `for (var q = 1; q < Cover + 1; q++) {
 (function(q){
  var oImage = new Image();
  oImage.onload = function () {
            document.getElementById('Image_' + q).src = oImage.src;
        };
  oImage.src = Images[q - 1]; 
 })(q);
};`

Comment: Спасибо!) Буду двигаться в задуманном направлении)